# Ubuntu Settings shows No Wifi Adapter found. But in lshw -C it shows Wifi Interface

Tags: networking, 22.04, adapter

1. I Use a HP Laptop containing Realtek `RTL8821CE` device and having Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy). I was trying to install droid cam which needed a secure boot key enrolling. Prior this step my wifi was working. But after that it shows No Wifi Adapter Found.

Note: Secured boot is enabled.

I checked the command lshw -C network command the below O/P:

```
*0800000-c0803fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.*
```

I have tried running the command as sudo.
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

It did not work.

I tried to check the Ubuntu software center but it is not launching.

I installed gnome-software and checked as a work around but it shows 'up to date' in that section.

I tried to make-install the rtw89 (from git) but yet not working.

Content of `iwlwifi.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d/`

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Content of `dkms.conf` (I commented- added #- to the last line)

```
# modprobe information used for DKMS modules
#
# This is a stub file, should be edited when needed,
# used by default by DKMS.
#blacklist rtw88_8821ce
```

Need a workable solution. Trying many things. Need Help

Answer (score 1):

The best driver for Realtek RTL8821CE is already packaged in the repositories but for some reason (likely a license issue) it isn't automatically installed.

Just run:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Reboot.

Comment: Firstly Thanks for the response. Tried not working.

Comment: Perhaps you should revert what you did in dkms.conf and disable Secure Boot in UEFI?